# Give EditText focus without showing the soft input

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-softkeyboard, android-custom-keyboard

I have an EditText configured in the following way because I have a custom keyboard to display:

```
    binding.editText.showSoftInputOnFocus = false
```

It works alright but I want to give the focus to the field when I load the screen, so I'm doing the following in my `onStart` method:

```
    binding.editText.requestFocus()
```

When I do this the default keyboard unfortunately shows and hide my custom keyboard.
How to give the focus to the EditText without showing the soft input?

Comment: what is the point of textfiled focus w/o IME?

Comment: I have a custom keyboard, first line: "I have an EditText configured in the following way because I have a custom keyboard to display:"

Comment: Custom mean in-app something? Then why you need EditText and not TextView?

Comment: I want to have a cursor when the user edit the text